# Thumbnails (Nautilus previews) for "basic" (xpm, png, bmp, gif) image files

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

Nautilus was not generating thumbnails for some `xpm` files I had, so I tried to investigate *who* was responsible for generating thumbnails for xpm files (if any), or any image for that matter. And I stumbled into a wall of misinformation, obsolete specs and frustrated searches.

So, *where* is the thumbnailer for such "basic" images defined? I've checked `/usr/share/thumbnailers` and it only mentions pdf, exe, and video files. No mention of png, jpg bmp, etc. Where are thumbnails of images defined? Wat are the official references about it?

Comment: It *is* weird, mine sure shows them. Can you add a screenshot? and what Nautilus version are you using?, have you tried with the settings in Nautilus? (Edit>Preferences>Preview)?.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Digging up further (and researching a LOT), I figured it out:

About image thumbnailers: It seems that Nautilus uses `libgnome-desktop` for thumbnail management, and the latter uses `libgdk-pixbuf` to handle file types that have no external handler in `/usr/share/thumbnailers`. So the "basic" image types are ultimately handled by [GnomeDesktopThumbnailFactory](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-desktop3/3.4/GnomeDesktopThumbnailFactory.html) and [GdkPixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.26/index.html) (references shown for versions shipped in Ubuntu 12.04). And the formats it handles can be inspected using the `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` tool. In my system this means:

```
The GdkPixdata format
['gdkp']
['image/x-gdkpixdata']

The Sun raster image format
['ras']
['image/x-cmu-raster', 'image/x-sun-raster']

The PNG image format
['png']
['image/png']

The WBMP image format
['wbmp']
['image/vnd.wap.wbmp']

The JPEG image format
['jpeg', 'jpe', 'jpg']
['image/jpeg']

The ANI image format
['ani']
['application/x-navi-animation']

The TIFF image format
['tiff', 'tif']
['image/tiff']

The XBM image format
['xbm']
['image/x-xbitmap']

The PCX image format
['pcx']
['image/x-pcx']

The Targa image format
['tga', 'targa']
['image/x-tga']

The PNM/PBM/PGM/PPM image format family
['pnm', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'ppm']
['image/x-portable-anymap', 'image/x-portable-bitmap',
 'image/x-portable-graymap', 'image/x-portable-pixmap']

The JPEG 2000 image format
['jp2', 'jpc', 'jpx', 'j2k', 'jpf']
['image/jp2', 'image/jpeg2000', 'image/jpx']

The ICNS image format
['icns']
['image/x-icns']

The BMP image format
['bmp']
['image/bmp', 'image/x-bmp', 'image/x-MS-bmp']

Windows Metafile
['wmf', 'apm']
['image/x-wmf']

The QTIF image format
['qtif', 'qif']
['image/x-quicktime', 'image/qtif']

Scalable Vector Graphics
['svg', 'svgz', 'svg.gz']
['image/svg+xml', 'image/svg', 'image/svg-xml', 'image/vnd.adobe.svg+xml',
 'text/xml-svg', 'image/svg+xml-compressed']

The ICO image format
['ico', 'cur']
['image/x-icon', 'image/x-ico', 'image/x-win-bitmap']

The XPM image format
['xpm']
['image/x-xpixmap']

The GIF image format
['gif']
['image/gif']
```

So *these* are the "internal" thumbnailers. And it does include `xpm` files. So something was wrong with my particular files instead.

And indeed the files were not standard, they had a copyright note prior to the `/* XPM *` header:

```
// This file is part of BOINC.
// http://boinc.berkeley.edu
//

/* XPM */
static const char *atiicon_xpm[] = {
```

Once comments were removed, thumbnails were generated just file.

It is curious that even with the "invalid" header the default Image Viewer in Gnome ("Eye of The Gnome", or `eog`) was able to display the files! So either files are not actually invalid, or kudos to `eog` for being able to open them! Anyway, since it *is* possible to open, and `eog` uses `gdk-pixbuf` too, I've [filled a bug in `libgnome-desktop`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699252) requesting that thumbnailers be generated for such non-standard `xpm` files. Any help promoting the bug is appreciated!

Also, some notes about my research:

[ThumbnailerSpec](https://live.gnome.org/ThumbnailerSpec) is mentioned in several places as the specification for "external thumbnailers". But it has nothing to do with this! It talks about using D-Bus for thumbnailers management, and nothing indicates that such spec is actually implemented in Gnome.

Actually, I was unable to find *any* official spec on the implemented behavior of *"saving a `.thumbnailer` file with `[Thumbnailer Entry]` and .desktop-esque format  to `/usr/share/thumbnailers`"*. [Bug 636819](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=636819#c29) is cited a lot as a source, but it only describes that behavior was changed in Gnome2->Gnome3 transition, and it no longer uses `gconf` to store external thumbnailers.

It looks like there is *no* spec at all. This [obsolete documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/3.4/thumbnailer.html.en) is still the *only* official reference, for example, on what `%i %o %u %s` means.

And the only "official" place announcing the change from `gconf` to `/usr/share/thumbnailers`, other than hunting down the [source code commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-desktop/commit/?id=3036c247dfd8c618671a010c8d9ddd4141062bfb) that did it, is this [seemingly ordinary bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638172).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more for your thorough analysis and follow-through! I'll likely refer others to this in the future as an exemplary self answer.

Comment: Thanks @ændrük ! I've spent like 12+ hours investigating this and gathering all the relevant info scattered all over the web. This answer was meant as a self-note of my findings, and I'm glad if it can spare others of wasting time on this like I did. Upvotes are appreciated, thanks.